# function is smooth iff the composition with any smooth curve is again smooth

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on the following part of a proof:

Let $\phi: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ be a function such that $\gamma'(t) := \phi(\gamma(t))$ is smooth for every smooth function $\gamma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$.

I want to show that $\phi$ is smooth under these assumptions.

Could someone give me a pointer?

Thanks in advance!

S.L.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is smooth iff each of the $n$ component functions of $\phi$ are smooth, you may as well assume $n=1$.  (I wish I had more information to give you!)

Comment: This is fantastic! I was about to ask this very question  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was proved by Jan Boman in the paper "Differentiability of a function and of its compositions with functions of one variable", [Math. Scand. 20 (1967)](http://www.mscand.dk/issue.php?year=1967&volume=20&issue=), 249-268.  (The theorem as stated is for the case $n=1$, but that is no problem as Jason DeVito already mentioned in a comment.)  [Here](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1825)'s an online version, and [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=237728)'s the MathSciNet link.  According to the article and review, it had been an unpublished conjecture of Rådström.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these links!

Comment: @S.L.: You're welcome.  Thank you for asking; I had fun finding the answer.

Comment: The old links to the article died.  Currently the following work: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/toc/?PPN=PPN35397434X_0020 for Math. Scand. 20 (1967), and http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/img/?PPN=PPN35397434X_0020&DMDID=dmdlog25 for the article.  (These may be added to the answer at some point if it seems worth it to "front page" the thread.)